# No video thumbnail preview Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I don't have any thumbnails displayed when the video is not launched on mobile, but on the web I do have the preview, if anyone has an idea, thanks.

```
<Video><video  playsInline controls width="300" height="300">
            <source
              src="4.mp4"
              type="video/mp4"
            />
            Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
          </video></Video>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is `Video` in the code?

Comment: styled components

Comment: Add `preload="metadata"` to `video`.

Comment: not working with that

Comment: What browser & device are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also on my React.js application only on a mobile view.
I've tried to add the preload="metadata" attribute without success, and also tried another hack to add this string at the end of the URL - "#t=0.001" that should stop the video one second before, and still the same issue.

I found a nice solution that also allows you to control the thumbnail by adding a poster attribute with a URL of the image that you want to display. it looks like that in the code:

```
<body>
    <video 
      width="400" 
      height="350" 
      controls 
      poster="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn- 
              uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <source 
          src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp- 
               content/uploads/20200409094356/Placement100-_-GeeksforGeeks2.mp4"
          type="video/mp4">
     </video>
</body>
```